# I have a local business on country code domain, I want to expand to global market

Tags: seo, optimization

I have a local business on a country code domain, I want to expand my business to global market, so I want to create a .com version of my site. But my domain is not available in .com

Can I use a different domain on .com ? for example: if my local site is: businessname.ca How Can I maintain my seo on google, while creating a global site with a different domain i.e. businessnameinternational.com

Will google be able to recognize that businessnameinternational.com is global version of my site businessname.ca

?

Answer (score 1):

Yes(ish). But you will need to help them.

There are several ways that Google, for example, will relate domain names.

1] Registration information. Make sure that the owner contact of the original and new domain match and that the contact information match. If this is not possible, then do the best you can. If these match, Google will credit the new domain with some small amount of trust and begin to make some assumptions.

2] On-site contact information. It is highly advisable that the About and/or Contact page of each domain contain contact information about the other site (if they differ or the same if they do not) as well as a link. In addition, schema.org mark-up should be used. Mark-up is trusted by Google more simply because there is no confusion what the data means. Using the contact information and links will relate the sites. This should include as much as makes sense including address, phone, e-mail addresses, etc. E-mail addresses are a particularly valuable data element.

3] Any personnel profiles. While most businesses forget this, personnel profiles are a strong additional signal to relate web sites. Again, use mark-up and as much information as you can including e-mail addresses. There should be some overlap between the sites or this will not work. Overlap can be CEO contact information for example. It can also be technical support, sales, etc.

4] Links from the home page. A simple link from the home page does not hurt either. Just do not make site wide links in headers, footers, or the sidebar. While there is some tolerance for this, I do not suggest risking a penalty.

5] Simple citations. A citation is a mention. In your content on both sites, mention the two sites in relation to how it fits best. You do not need a link per se', just a mention. A link could be good along side a citation. Since citations are a signal as well as link, why not use both?

6] Home page title. And any other page title that makes sense, place the company name. If you manage the title tag properly, you should be able to brand each site: one, the local/regional site; and two, the international site. Do this how you see fit. Branding title tags is a strong signal. Make them similar, but not identical.

That should be enough. You do not need all of these things, but strive for as much as possible and give as much detail as you can that makes sense for your situation.

Comment: I agree with 4th and 6th point :)

Comment: @Goyllo It is all factual. I have been at this a long time and do not parrot what other silly-*** SEOs say, but read the patents, research papers, engineers books, etc. As well, I have done some research that Google was very interested in and applies including analysis of registration and network information for trust. As a result of this, they shared some internal documents that any SEO would kill for. It was extremely detailed on what was used, how it was used, a schema (of sorts), methods, factors, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how, Google understand your all websites.

1) Add your website on Google Webmaster Tools, and set target country location for each website, hence google don't show your Canada(.ca) website in other Google search domain like Google.co.in or Google.com.au

2) Link your child website(Country website) to Main Website(International website). I don't suggest to interlink country to country website, but if you have few sites like 3 or 4, then Go ahead. And don't interlink on sidebar or footer, I suggest to interlink them in main top bar/navigation.

3) Use same company name.

4) Do not add same product in multiple site or use different currency with same product. In reality **Google is smart enough to understand same product with different currency.**

5) Google does not use Domain Register info(since webmaster may be use who is privacy), About or contact us page is OK for main website, no need to create same about page for local website, if you point your local about/contact page to main site, then Google can easily understand, you have multi-business site.

6) You can create Multiple Google My Business pages, which are used, most time in Google local search.

Comment: *5) Google does not use Domain Register info* is completely untrue! They have used registration information since the very earliest days and the reason why they are a registrar. This comes from Googles own documentation and is not up to opinion.

Comment: I really like to read official document on that. As per wikipedia page, different govt have it's different rule for domain registration, some country allowed to access who is data for private organization, and some are not. So I don't think Google use who is information for that. And what if I use same details just like you i.e. same name, phone number, address etc. Then Google will treat this domain is related to this?

Comment: Whois information is required as participation, however, you are right about some of the data being public through whois look-ups. Remember, that whois is not the only tool available. Google uses registration information as part of their trust metrics and spam detection. Period. It has for a long time. Again, I have had access to some Google internal documentation. I am telling you this as a fact and not as an opinion.